# Setting up Xcode service in OS X server

Tags: xcode, osx-server

I configured a new OS X Server with Xcode service. And it worked smoothly. But after restarting of machine the Xcode service stopped. On turning it on again, it asks for Xcode instance to run and after that it gets stuck on 'Waiting for Xcode setup to complete'. Also there is a new user logged in '_xcsbuildd' which I cannot access.

How to reconfigure the Xcode service here? Also is there any way to safely reboot so system to avoid such situation in future

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fixed it by running following command on terminal:

```
sudo xcrun xcscontrol --reset
```

Refer the link https://devforums.apple.com/message/1053273#1053273.